# How do I deal with a special word in a bigquery nested record with dot notation

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dot notation, and it would work fine if the word order was not in the column.  I'm having difficulty using the word order in the dot notation table.  Any help would be appreciated how to handle this case.

```
SELECT order.merchantOrderId
FROM `MYTABLE`
LIMIT 1000
```

Gives me the following error.

```
Syntax error: Unexpected keyword ORDER at [1:8]
```

Reading the docs the notation to deal with this, seems to be to do the following.

```
SELECT ['order'].merchantOrderId
FROM `MYTABLE`
LIMIT 1000
```

Which sends the following error.

```
 Cannot access field merchantOrderId on a value with type ARRAY<STRING> at [1:18]
```

Comment: Where did you find that syntax in the documentation? Are you sure it shouldn't be `[order].merchantOrderId` or `[order.merchantOrderId]`? (I'm asking sincerely since I'm not very familiar with BigQuery).

Comment: The documentation is pretty bad and doesn't go over that.  I've only found it from other stack overflow posts.

Comment: It works in a query that doesn't have to use dot syntax.

Comment: `order` is a reserved keyword, so should be quoted with backtick like `\`order\``.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked.

```
SELECT `order`.merchantOrderId
FROM `MYTABLE`
LIMIT 1000
```